# Trying to insert a digital signature line in a docx file

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx

I'm trying to insert a digital signature line in an openxml (docx) version of a word document. I don't get any errors but I realize I might be missing a step. Here's my code. It's a windows forms application. Can some one tell me how to properly append a digital signature line to a Run instance? The //S// serves as a marker where we want to insert the digital signature line. It's easy to find with a foreach statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace KeywordSearch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FileInfo[] tempfiles;
        List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = txtPath.Text;
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                foreach (Text t in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>())
                {
                    if (t.Text == "//S//")
                    {
                        lbxResults.Items.Add(t.Text);

                        Run r = (Run)t.Parent;

                        SignatureLine signature = new SignatureLine();
                        signature.SuggestedSigner = "Pete Smith";
                        signature.SuggestedSigner2 = "Programmer";
                        signature.SuggestedSignerEmail = "pete.smith@navy.mil";
                        signature.SigningInstructions = "Please sign";
                        signature.ShowSignDate = true;
                        signature.AllowComments = true;



                        r.AppendChild<SignatureLine>(signature);
                    }
                }
            }

            lbxResults.Items.Add("Completed adding digital signature liens.");
        }
    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        txtPath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

This code contains a function `AddSiganture()` which searches for a ContentControl with tag "topsoft", and adds a `SignatureLine` to it. More information about the SignatureLine can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.vml.office.signatureline.aspx 
Actually a signature line is a Picture with a shape and a shape type inside. Also it's very important to add an ImagePart to the document with a corresponding ID. The ID of the image part must correspond to the `RelationshipId` of the image object inside the Picture object.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using Ap = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties;
using Vt = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.VariantTypes;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using V = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml;
using Ovml = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Vml.Office;
using Ds = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomXmlDataProperties;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using M = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Tigran\Documents\qw.docx", true))
            {
                AddSiganture(document, "Tigran Topchyan", "Head of Development", "tigran.topchyan@gmail.com");
                document.Close();
            } 
        }

        public void AddSiganture(WordprocessingDocument document, string signerName, string signerTitle, string signerEmail)
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart1 = document.MainDocumentPart;

            string imagePartID = "ID_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            string signatureID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B");
            Picture picture1 = new Picture();

            V.Shapetype shapetype1 = new V.Shapetype() { Id = "_x0000_t75", CoordinateSize = "21600,21600", Filled = false, Stroked = false, OptionalNumber = 75, PreferRelative = true, EdgePath = "m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" };
            V.Stroke stroke1 = new V.Stroke() { JoinStyle = V.StrokeJoinStyleValues.Miter };

            V.Formulas formulas1 = new V.Formulas();
            V.Formula formula1 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0" };
            V.Formula formula2 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum @0 1 0" };
            V.Formula formula3 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum 0 0 @1" };
            V.Formula formula4 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @2 1 2" };
            V.Formula formula5 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @3 21600 pixelWidth" };
            V.Formula formula6 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @3 21600 pixelHeight" };
            V.Formula formula7 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum @0 0 1" };
            V.Formula formula8 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @6 1 2" };
            V.Formula formula9 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @7 21600 pixelWidth" };
            V.Formula formula10 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum @8 21600 0" };
            V.Formula formula11 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod @7 21600 pixelHeight" };
            V.Formula formula12 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum @10 21600 0" };

            formulas1.Append(formula1);
            formulas1.Append(formula2);
            formulas1.Append(formula3);
            formulas1.Append(formula4);
            formulas1.Append(formula5);
            formulas1.Append(formula6);
            formulas1.Append(formula7);
            formulas1.Append(formula8);
            formulas1.Append(formula9);
            formulas1.Append(formula10);
            formulas1.Append(formula11);
            formulas1.Append(formula12);
            V.Path path1 = new V.Path() { AllowGradientShape = true, ConnectionPointType = Ovml.ConnectValues.Rectangle, AllowExtrusion = false };
            Ovml.Lock lock1 = new Ovml.Lock() { Extension = V.ExtensionHandlingBehaviorValues.Edit, AspectRatio = true };

            shapetype1.Append(stroke1);
            shapetype1.Append(formulas1);
            shapetype1.Append(path1);
            shapetype1.Append(lock1);

            V.Shape shape1 = new V.Shape() 
            {
                Id = "_x0000_i1025", 
                Style = "width:192pt;height:96pt", 
                Alternate = "Microsoft Office Signature Line...", 
                Type = "#_x0000_t75" 
            };
            V.ImageData imageData1 = new V.ImageData() { Title = "", RelationshipId = imagePartID };

            Ovml.Lock lock2 = new Ovml.Lock()
            { 
                Extension = V.ExtensionHandlingBehaviorValues.Edit, 
                Grouping = true, Ungrouping = true, Rotation = true, Cropping = true, Verticies = true, TextLock = true 
            };

            Ovml.SignatureLine signatureLine1 = new Ovml.SignatureLine() 
            {
                Extension = V.ExtensionHandlingBehaviorValues.Edit, 
                IsSignatureLine = true, 
                Id = signatureID, 
                ProviderId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}", 
                SuggestedSigner = signerName, 
                SuggestedSigner2 = signerTitle,
                SuggestedSignerEmail = signerEmail
            };

            shape1.Append(imageData1);
            shape1.Append(lock2);
            shape1.Append(signatureLine1);

            picture1.Append(shapetype1);
            picture1.Append(shape1);

            var contentControls = mainDocumentPart1.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>();
            foreach (SdtElement elem in contentControls)
            {
                if (elem.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "topsoft")
                {
                    var content = elem.GetFirstChild<SdtContentBlock>();
                    content.RemoveAllChildren();
                    content.Append(picture1);
                }
            }

            ImagePart imagePart1 = mainDocumentPart1.AddNewPart<ImagePart>("image/x-emf", imagePartID);
            GenerateImagePartContent(imagePart1);
        }

        public void GenerateImagePartContent(ImagePart imagePart1)
        {
            System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(imagePart1Data);
            imagePart1.FeedData(data);
            data.Close();
        }

        #region Binary Data
        public string imagePart1Data = "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";

        public System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
        {
            return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added an upgrade to the answer posted by Tigran Topchyan.

Which enables me to generate the signatureline image at runtime. instead of having the imagePart1Data hardcoded into the docx file. which will show when you open the word document with another program such as notepad or in protected mode.

I've added the following to my resources: an empty signatureline image
[image]

Then I've added the reference to system.drawing 
Then add the following to your class where you have his code (using System.Drawing).

Then you need to replace the following code in the region binary data:

```
    public string imagePart1Data = "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";

    public System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
    {
        return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
    }
```

with this:

```
    private System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string nameToPrint, string functionToPrint)
    {
        return new System.IO.MemoryStream(CreateImageForSignatureLine(nameToPrint, functionToPrint));
    }


    private byte[] CreateImageForSignatureLine(string nameToPrint, string functionToPrint)
    {
        using (Image img = new Bitmap(My.Resources.SignatureLineEmpty))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameToPrint))
            {
                DrawNameOnImage(img, nameToPrint);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(functionToPrint))
            {
                DrawFunctionOnImage(img, functionToPrint);
            }
            DrawFunctionOnImage(img, functionToPrint);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }


    private void DrawNameOnImage(Image img, string nameToPrint)
    {
        DrawOnSignature(img, nameToPrint, 7, 80);
    }
    private void DrawFunctionOnImage(Image img, string functionToPrint)
    {
        DrawOnSignature(img, functionToPrint, 7, 96);
    }

    private void DrawOnSignature(Image img, string text, int x, int y)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8))
        {
            using (Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, x, y);
                drawing.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone.